# How to make clicking specific option from selectbox jump to a specific URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form (code below) where each time you click on an option, a button appears with the proper value sent to it. Clicking it takes you to a processing form offsite. This part works fine. What I need is for one of the options, say option 3 to take you separate URL. I'm already using the onchange for the selectbox. Is there a way to do multiple onchange functions? Possibly target by option id? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
<script>
    function clicker(frm,value,button) {
        frm.LinkId.value = value;
        if (value != "") {
            document.getElementById(button).style.display = "inline"; 
        } else {
            document.getElementById(button).style.display = "none"; 
        }
    }
</script>

<form name="PrePage" align="center" id="Prepage" method ="post" style="width:190px; text-align:center;" action= "https://Simplecheckout.authorize.net/payment/CatalogPayment.aspx">
    <label for="selectbox" style="font-family: rockwell, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size:1.5em"; width:190px; text-align:left;">This donation is for:</label>
    <select style="margin:0 0 30px 0; width:180px;" size="1" name="selectbox" id="selectbox" onchange="clicker(document.PrePage,document.PrePage.selectbox.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'button');" >
    <option selected value=""></option>
    <option value="value1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="value4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="value5">Option 5</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="LinkId" id="LinkId" value="" /><input id="button" style="display:none; margin:0 0 30px 0; text-align:center;" type="image" src="images/donate_button.gif" alt="Donate" />
</form>
```

Comment: I'm sure people would be very happy to help if you want to share your code with where you've got up to on this task so-far.  What is it specifically that you're stumbling on?

Comment: Daniel's code is exactly what I need it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check the value and change the form action url accordingly.... like:

```
function clicker(frm,value,button) {
    if (value == 'value3')
        frm.action = "http://www.google.com";
    else
        frm.action = "https://Simplecheckout.authorize.net/payment/CatalogPayment.aspx";

    frm.LinkId.value = value;
    if (value != "") {
        document.getElementById(button).style.display = "inline"; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById(button).style.display = "none"; 
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.